# Migrating site to another server. Error in with relative URL

Tags: url-rewriting, migrate

I am migrating a site to another server, and all images and files like JS and CSS are with relative URL. `(EX: src = "/image/image.jpg")`.

The problem is that the new server is not working because I am using a temporary URL to test `(EX: /ipaddress/~sitename/)`.

I tried using the following code in. Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ipaddress/~sitename/
```

But it did not work.

I also thought about creating a DEFINE, but I'll have to change all (`EX: src = "DEFINENAME / images / image.jpg"`). And the site is very large.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two methods to solve:

```
1 - Hiring dedicated IP's.
2 - Changing the DNS and testing, or a subdomain.
```